# Convert data of overlapping time ranges to data of distinct time ranges

Tags: r, dataframe, range, overlap

I have data that consists of observations of the range of time a particular status applied for an individual. An individual can have multiple statuses at a given time, or have no stats at all (in which case there would not be an observation).

```
ID  STATUS START      END    
1   A      2013-03-07 2013-04-20
1   B      2013-04-10 2013-05-10
1   C      2013-04-16 2013-07-11
1   B      2013-07-25 2013-08-08
2   A      2013-09-10 2014-04-21
2   C      2013-12-27 2014-01-26
2   D      2014-04-28 2014-05-10
2   E      2014-05-11 2014-07-16
```

I would like to convert this into a dataframe consisting of distinct, non-overlapping periods and all of the statuses that applied during those periods. The result from the example would be as below.

```
ID  STATUS START      END    
1   A      2013-03-07 2013-04-10
1   A,B    2013-04-10 2013-04-16
1   A,B,C  2013-04-16 2013-04-20
1   B,C    2013-04-20 2013-05-10
1   C      2013-05-10 2013-07-11
1   B      2013-07-25 2013-08-08
2   A      2013-09-10 2013-12-27
2   A,C    2013-12-27 2014-01-26
2   D      2014-04-28 2014-05-10
2   E      2014-05-11 2014-07-16
```

My data is fairly large, and so I struggling to find an efficient way to do this. I've found semi-related problems, such as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16957293/collapse-intersecting-regions), but they typically involve collapsing overlapping regions into a super region, rather than breaking them out into distinct subregions.

Any help or ideas would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: What would define the periods exactly? Like how do you decide a period is 2013-03-07 thru 2013-04-16?

Comment: I think that this is what you basically need: [Find overlapping dates for each ID and create a new row for the overlap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46151452/find-overlapping-dates-for-each-id-and-create-a-new-row-for-the-overlap)

Comment: As a starting point, you can concatenate your start and end points into a single vector, and then sort it uniquely in ascending order, e.g. `breakpoints <- sort(unique(c(dt$START, dt$END)))`. Then create a new table where `START = c(-Inf, breakpoints)` and `END = c(breakpoints,Inf)`. This will be your set of distinct, non-overlapping ranges.

Comment: @bk18 In the data I have, a row defines an unbroken period of a particular status (for example, status A). So if I’m on status A for month, then go off of it for a week, and then back on, those would show up as two separate rows. Also, there can be other statuses that are simultaneously, which would be defined by their own rows.

Answer (score 2):

```
library(dplyr)

# Create all the possible date ranges
date_breaks <- sort(c(df$START, df$END))

# Build a data.frame with all possible combinations
df2 <- expand.grid(START = head(date_breaks, -1),
                   ID = unique(df$ID),
                   STATUS = unique(df$STATUS),
                   stringsAsFactors = F)
df2$END <- tail(date_breaks, -1)

# Join in original data and filter to where the start and end are in range
df2 %>%
    inner_join(df, by = c("ID", "STATUS")) %>%
    filter(START.y <= START.x, END.y >= END.x) %>%
    group_by(ID, START = START.x, END = END.x) %>%
    summarise(STATUS = paste(unique(STATUS), collapse = ', ')) %>% 
    select(ID, STATUS, START, END)

#  A tibble: 11 x 4
#  Groups:   ID, START [11]
#       ID STATUS  START      END       
#    <int> <chr>   <date>     <date>    
#  1     1 A       2013-03-07 2013-04-10
#  2     1 A, B    2013-04-10 2013-04-16
#  3     1 A, B, C 2013-04-16 2013-04-20
#  4     1 B, C    2013-04-20 2013-05-10
#  5     1 C       2013-05-10 2013-07-11
#  6     1 B       2013-07-25 2013-08-08
#  7     2 A       2013-09-10 2013-12-27
#  8     2 A, C    2013-12-27 2014-01-26
#  9     2 A       2014-01-26 2014-04-21
# 10     2 D       2014-04-28 2014-05-10
# 11     2 E       2014-05-11 2014-07-16
```

**Data**

```
df <- read.table(text = "ID  STATUS START      END    
                         1   A      2013-03-07 2013-04-20
                         1   B      2013-04-10 2013-05-10
                         1   C      2013-04-16 2013-07-11
                         1   B      2013-07-25 2013-08-08
                         2   A      2013-09-10 2014-04-21
                         2   C      2013-12-27 2014-01-26
                         2   D      2014-04-28 2014-05-10
                         2   E      2014-05-11 2014-07-16",
                 header = T,
                 colClasses = c('integer', 'character', 'Date', 'Date'))
```