# Overlaping periodes, grouping activities throught IDs with R

Tags: r

I have a data set with IDs, begin date, end date, activity status.
The current data set counts 150.000 rows and 50.000 IDs but will be much bigger.

I would like with R regrouping on the same row for the same ID and the same periods (begin date and end dates), the different activities occurring  on an overlapping period.

In other words, I try to:
1) reshaping the data to get overlap and non-overlap periods in specific rows.
2) pasting together overlapping activity status.

I already tried:

[Find overlapping dates for each ID and create a new row for the overlap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46151452/find-overlapping-dates-for-each-id-and-create-a-new-row-for-the-overlap/46171724#46171724)

and

[Convert data of overlapping time ranges to data of distinct time ranges](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52010252/convert-data-of-overlapping-time-ranges-to-data-of-distinct-time-ranges/52011136#52011136)

Both of these solutions are very good and helped me a lot.

However these two approaches cannot handle in a one piece all the data set of 150.000 rows. I used the second solution by dividing my data set. I needed 2 hours to analyse 18 000 rows.

I wonder if some solution could be more efficient on R. I was thinking using mutate but I'm not very familiar with that function.

The input data looks like this:

```
ID  START   END STATUS  
5c0e83  2013-11-01  2015-01-01  P1  
5c0e83  2002-09-01  2003-09-01  F2  
5c0e83  2016-09-01  2016-09-01  F0  
5c0e83  2006-01-01  2007-01-01  P3  
5c0e83  2003-11-01  2013-11-01  P2  
5c0e83  2015-09-01  2018-01-01  P0  
5c0e83  2003-09-01  2005-09-01  F1
```

Thanks the script previously cited the output have been like this
([Convert data of overlapping time ranges to data of distinct time ranges](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52010252/convert-data-of-overlapping-time-ranges-to-data-of-distinct-time-ranges/52011136#52011136))

```
ID  STATUS  START   END
5c0e83  F3  2002-09-01  2002-09-01
5c0e83  F3  2002-09-01  2002-10-01
5c0e83  F3  2002-10-01  2002-10-01
5c0e83  F3  2002-10-01  2002-11-01
5c0e83  F3  2002-11-01  2002-11-01
5c0e83  F3  2002-11-01  2003-01-01
5c0e83  F3  2003-01-01  2003-01-01
5c0e83  F3  2003-01-01  2003-09-01
5c0e83  F3, F2  2003-09-01  2003-09-01
5c0e83  F2  2003-09-01  2003-10-01
5c0e83  F2  2003-10-01  2003-10-01
5c0e83  F2  2003-10-01  2003-11-01
5c0e83  F2, P2  2003-11-01  2003-11-01
5c0e83  F2, P2  2003-11-01  2004-01-01
5c0e83  F2, P2  2004-01-01  2004-01-01
5c0e83  F2, P2  2004-01-01  2004-09-01
5c0e83  F2, P2  2004-09-01  2004-09-01
5c0e83  F2, P2  2004-09-01  2004-10-01
5c0e83  F2, P2  2004-10-01  2004-10-01
5c0e83  F2, P2  2004-10-01  2004-11-01
```

The result is good but the time for treatment is very long.
I wonder if someone thinks about a more efficient way to perform this task.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Where does the STATUS `F3`in the output come from?

Comment: I only putted an extract from the input and output to inform that the shape of my data is the same from the cited examples. Sorry for the lack of precision.

Answer (score 0):

This is a little faster than [the solution you linked to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52010252/convert-data-of-overlapping-time-ranges-to-data-of-distinct-time-ranges/52011136#52011136) on the sample data, but I hope significantly faster on your larger data.

My approach was to bring the data into long form, pad each ID-STATUS to get a row for every month in the range, then get the combos for each ID-date, then extract the START and END of each combo and spread it wide again.

```
library(tidyverse)
df2 <- df %>%
  gather(type, date, START, END) %>%
  group_by(ID, STATUS) %>%
  padr::pad(group = c("ID", "STATUS"), interval = "1 month") %>%
  distinct(ID, STATUS, date) %>%  # For statuses that only last 1 month, only need one row, not both

  # Adapted from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52010252/convert-data-of-overlapping-time-ranges-to-data-of-distinct-time-ranges/52011136#52011136
  group_by(ID, date) %>%
  summarize(STATUS = paste(unique(STATUS), collapse = ", ")) %>%

  mutate(type = case_when(row_number() == 1   | STATUS != lag(STATUS)  ~ "START",
                          row_number() == n() | STATUS != lead(STATUS) ~ "END",
                          TRUE  ~ NA_character_)) %>%
  filter(!is.na(type)) %>%

  # This last part is to reshape the data to be wide again, with the first line
  #   to keep re-introduced combinations distinct from prior occurences
  group_by(ID, STATUS) %>% mutate(cycle = cumsum(type == "START")) %>% ungroup() %>%
  spread(type, date) %>%
  mutate(END = if_else(is.na(END), START, END))
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help.

Your solution is providing a huge gain of time. From 2 hours I get down to few seconds to treat 12.000 rows.

However, when I load a bigger data frame (150.000 rows) I get the following error:

> Error: Estimated 3040980.62465753 returned rows, larger than 1 million in break_above
>
> Traceback:
>   1. df_ml2 %>% gather(type, date, START, END) %>% group_by(ID, STATUS) %>% padr::pad(group = c("ID", "STATUS"), interval = "1 month") %>% 
>   distinct(ID, STATUS, date) %>% group_by(ID, date) %>% summarize(STATUS = paste(unique(STATUS), collapse = ", ")) %>% mutate(type = case_when(row_number() ==
>
> 1 | STATUS != lag(STATUS) ~ "START", row_number() == n() |STATUS != lead(STATUS) ~ "END", TRUE ~ NA_character_)) %>% filter(!is.na(type)) %>% group_by(ID, STATUS) %>% mutate(cycle = cumsum(type == 
>   "START")) %>% ungroup() %>% spread(type, date) %>% mutate(END = if_else(is.na(END),START, END))
>   2. withVisible(eval(quote(`_fseq`(`_lhs`)), env, env))
>
> 3. eval(quote(`_fseq`(`_lhs`)), env, env)
> 4. eval(quote(`_fseq`(`_lhs`)), env, env)
> 5. `_fseq`(`_lhs`)
> 6. freduce(value, `_function_list`)
> 7. function_list[i]
> 8. padr::pad(., group = c("ID", "STATUS"), interval = "1 month")
> 9. break_above_func(return_rows, break_above)
> 10. stop(sprintf("Estimated %s returned rows, larger than %s million in break_above", n, threshold), call. = FALSE)

Does the solution consists to apply the script on a list of datasets or there is a way to go beyond the million break-above?

Thanks again for your help.